# Magento 1.9 Helper not found error

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to create new link in admin panel, which leads to helper not found error. My config files are as follows.

> app\code\local\Ddevs\Ebayaff\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ddevs_Ebayaff>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Ddevs_Ebayaff>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <add_category_attribute>
                <setup>
                    <module>Ddevs_Ebayaff</module>
                    <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </add_category_attribute>
        </resources>
        <helpers>
            <ebayaff>
                <class>Ddevs_Ebayaff_Helper</class>
            </ebayaff>
        </helpers>
    </global>

   <admin>
        <routers>

           <samplerouter1>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Ddevs_Ebayaff_AdminControllersHere</module>
                    <frontName>admin</frontName>

                    <modules>
                        <sintax after="Ddevs_Ebayaff_AdminControllersHere">Mage_Adminhtml</sintax>
                    </modules>
                </args>
           </samplerouter1>          



         </routers>     
    </admin>
```

> app\code\local\Ddevs\Ebayaff\etc\adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>

        <menu>
             <mymenu1 translate="title" module="ebayaff">
                <title>Ebay aff</title>
                <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                <children>

                    <myitem1 translate="title" module="samplerouter1">
                        <title>Simple one column layout with custom template file assigned for viewsss</title>
                        <action>samplerouter1/FreakOut</action>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>                        
                    </myitem1>
                </children>
             </mymenu1>
        </menu>   
</config>
```

> app\code\local\Ddevs\Ebayaff\Helper\Data.php

```
<?php

class Ddevs_Ebayaff_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data
{

}
```

And I am getting the following error.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Ebayaff_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/html/demoshop/app/Mage.php on line 547
```

Comment: need to change "samplerouter1" to "ebayaff" in config.xml

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear or refresh Magento cache whenever you change `config.xml` file and cache is enabled.
So please do the same if Magento cache was enabled in your case.